# Generate Multiple POJO's from single json schema file

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I am using **jsonschema2pojo** to generate POJO's. Its working fine. 
But I want to generate multiple POJO's from single json schema file. 
Is this possible using **jsonschema2pojo** plugin.

One way to generate multiple POJO's is to provide multiple json schema files, but i don't want to do that. I want to provide only one json schema file as input.

I am providing following json schema as input:

```
{
  "Address": {
    "description": "AnAddressfollowingtheconventionofhttp: //microformats.org/wiki/hcard",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "post-office-box": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "post-office-address": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "AddressDetails": {
    "description": "AnAddressDetailsfollowingtheconventionofhttp: //microformats.org/wiki/hcard",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "post-office-box": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "post-office-address": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Above schema is valid schema but nothing gets created. I don't know If I am missing something or its just not possible using **jsonschema2pojo**.

Also is there a way to generate these entities at run-time?

If anyone has any thoughts on the same, do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to split these into separate files, or reference these schemas from another file like:

```
{"$ref" : "schemas/myfile.json#AddressDetails"}
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of an ugly workaround for this by letting jsonschema2pojo generate an outer "trash" object, which contained

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"description":"Do not use outer object, it's merely a schema wrapper for the inner objects.",
"id":"http://some-path",
"type":"object",
"properties": {
<all your objects go here>
}
```

...it will leave you with a trash object, but let you define all your objects in one schema. I would also really have liked a cleaner solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website and I am able to generate multiple POJO from single JSON file. They also have ZIP option to download all the files at once.